# DEPRECATION: Versions of modifier manager capabilities prior to 3.22 have been deprecated. You must update to the 3.22 capabilities

Tags: ember.js

I got this warning on my Ember App :

> DEPRECATION: Versions of modifier manager capabilities prior to 3.22 have been deprecated. You must update to the 3.22 capabilities. [deprecation id: manager-capabilities.modifiers-3-13] See https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x#toc_manager-capabilities-modifiers-3-13 for more details.
> at logDeprecationStackTrace (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36552:21)
> at HANDLERS. (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36685:9)
> at raiseOnDeprecation (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36579:9)
> at HANDLERS. (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36685:9)
> at invoke (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36697:9)
> at deprecate (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:36653:28)
> at modifierCapabilities$1 (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:11678:62)
> at http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:99939:46
> at CustomModifierManager.getDelegateFor (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:44817:20)

I visited the link [https://deprecations.emberjs.com/](https://deprecations.emberjs.com/v3.x#toc_manager-capabilities-modifiers-3-13) recommended  for updating, I didn't really understand how to make this update, any help please .

Comment: it might be also caused by an addon. Is it the full stack trace?

Comment: I used to see this message when using ember-could-get-used-to-this add-on, there's nothing you can do here, only waiting for add-on upgrades itself or silent this deprecation by using ember-cli-deprecations-workflow

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is answered in a comment, rather than an answer (also, addon-devs need to make sure they're using the latest capabilities)